# $f \in H(B(0,1))$ if only if $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f\left(e^{i t}\right) e^{i n t}=0$ for all $n \geq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f:\overline{B(0,1)} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f \in H(B(0,1))$ if only if $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f\left(e^{i t}\right) e^{i n t}=0$ for all $n \geq 1$

I have tried to remplace $f\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_{r}(\theta-t) f\left(e^{i t}\right) d t$  for all  $r e^{i \theta} \in \mathbb{D}$ but i can't conclude.

Comment: What is $H(B(0,1))$? One way implication does not even make sense without any information on $f$.

Comment: Holomorphic functions from $\overline{B(0,1)}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: A function for which the integrals are $0$ need not even be continuous. Are you assuming continuity of $f$ on the close disk?

Comment: Yes, the function is continuous in the close.

Comment: I think the statement is garbled - one correct statement is that given a continuous function on the unit circle $f$, there is a holomorphic function (call it also $f$ by a little abuse of notation) in the open unit disc, continuous on the circle and equal to the given original $f$ on the circle if and only if $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f\left(e^{i t}\right) e^{i n t}=0, n \ge 1$; this is called Riesz theorem (and holds for $f$ integrable on the circle and then its holomorphic extension has the original $f$ as a radial limit ae say)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously false. There exists a continuous function in the closed disk which is $0$ on the boundary but not holomorphic inside: Example: $f(z)=1-|z|$.

On way implication follows from Cauchy's Theorem applied to the function $f(z)z^{n-1}$ to  the circle of radius $1-\epsilon$ around $0$ and then letting $\epsilon \to 0$.

Edit: 'if only if' is confusing. If you are asking for one way implication the my second paragraph above gives an answer.

Comment: that function fulfills the theorem.

Comment: No. It fulfills the condition $\int f(e^{it})e^{int}dt=0$ for all $n \geq 1$ but it is not holomorphic.  $|z|$ is not holomorphic.

Comment: What is 'if only if'? Is it 'if and only if' or just 'only if'?. See  my EDIT.